# Is it always the case that an infinite set has a proper subset equal in cardinality to itself?

Tags: set-theory

In Paul R. Halmos's book "Naive Set Theory," in the latter part of section 13 related to arithmetic, there is a definition for a finite set: a set is finite if there is a bijection between it and a natural number $n$. It is proven in the same section that every natural number $n$ cannot be bijected with any proper subset of it. Additionally, it is demonstrated, concerning the set of natural numbers ($\omega$), that there exists a proper subset that bijects with it; in other words, a part of it equals the whole. This led me to intuitively infer that every infinite set must have a proper subset that bijects with it; otherwise, it is a finite set. Please, is there a proof for this assertion?

Comment: The assertion is false, but to construct counterexamples you need forcing.

Comment: Being able to put a set into a bijection with a proper subset of itself is my favorite definition of infinite sets. A finite set is not infinite. This notion is called Dedekind infinite. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set

Comment: Your assertion is true if you also assume the Axiom of Choice.  In the absence of choice, it need not be true -- in a world where the Axiom of Choice fails, there can be infinite sets that are Dedekind finite.

Comment: @ChadK Is there a reference you can suggest regarding this matter?

Comment: @RobertShore I never expected the Axiom of Choice to play a role here. It's fascinating. Thank you, sir, for the guidance.

Comment: @BezinaTaki:  See Paul J. Cohen "Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis" (1966), Section 9, page 138 Theorem 1 "$N$ is a model for ZF in which the set $T$ is a subset of $P(\Bbb{N})$ such that $T$ is infinite and yet contains no countable subset."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that your definition of an infinite set is that it's not in a bijection with a natural number.

Let $X$ be your infinite set. Let $F$ be a mapping from nonempty subsets of $X$ to elements of that subset, i.e. $F(Y) \in Y$.

By induction, define the sequence $a_n$:
$$a_n = F(X - \{a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1}\})$$

And now define $g: X \to X$:

$g(a_n) = a_{n+1}$

$g(x) = x$ for other $x$.

$g$ is a bijection from $X$ to a proper subset of itself, namely $X - \{a_0\}$

Comment: @BezinaTaki In case you're wondering, you need the Axiom of Choice to know that the function $F$ exists.

Comment: The book uses ZFC as its foundation, so there is no problem with the axiom of choice -- it is an axiom after all.

Comment: @TomekCzajkaThank you for the helpful answer, I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: To be fair to @RobertShore , at this point in the book Halmos has, as yet, not introduced choice.